# Start process via SSH and GDB?

Tags: linux, ssh, gdb

This question sounds very stupid to me, but if this is somehow possible it would be really helpful.

My application is crashing and I need to debug it. And I run this application in another computer, via SSH (it's an HTTP server). If I could leave a terminal running the application over GDB and SSH all the time, I'd be able to find the bugs. But I don't have a free computer to do that. What can I do? Is there a way to start GDB with [`nohup(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) plus `&>` and stuff like that, so I can see GDB output (`where` command, for example) later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical Unix program called `screen` is your friend (or its competitor `tmux`). It allows to keep a virtual console open across multiple logins:

```
screen
```

starts such a session; using  you can detach from that; using

```
screen -r
```

you can reconnect to it later.

However, you don't even need that; just make your program leave a core dump when it crashes; `ulimit -c unlimited` says "every program that crashes leaves a core dump"; you can then just open the core dump using gdb later on, and everything will be as if you ran the program inside gdb when it crashed.

```
gdb core.123456
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me!

Comment: The crash happened, but no core dump file was left. Maybe the process is not receiving a signal whose default action is to leave a core dump and exit. How can I detach from `screen` when inside gdb's prompt? Is that possible?

Comment: same key combination :)